# Keep certain rows and deleting certain rows

Tags: excel, matlab

I imported a few thousand rows of data into Excel and hence one data represented one row. I want to keep row no. 1, 11, 21, 31,.... and deleting row 2 to 10, 12 to 20, 22 to 30,.... and so on. Please anybody help me.

Comment: How is this related to Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

This worked really well. It's super fast too. Just paste this into a module. It will find the last row with data in it, select all the rows you want to delete, then delete them all at once ;)

```
Public Sub DeleteRows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlPart, xlRows, xlPrevious).Row

Set rng = Range("A2:A10")

For j = 11 To i Step 10
    Set rng = Union(rng, Range(Range("A1").Offset(j, 0), Range("A1").Offset(j + 8)))
    i = i - 10
Next

rng.Delete shift:=xlUp

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it - assuming your column A has the most data to set the lastRow on:

```
Sub remove_rows()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -10
    Range(Cells(i - 1, 1), Cells(i - 9, 1)).Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Note when removing rows, it's best practice to start at the *end* and move upwards. Hence the `Step -10`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (if you plan to use Matlab and not VBA):

```
   % Suppose the variable "mydata" contains your data ^^
    nbrows = length(mydata);

    % id will contains only [1, 11, 21, ..., 1001, ...]
    id = nan(floor(nbrows/10), 1);
    zz = 1;
    for ii = 1:nbrows
       if mod(ii, 10) == 1
           id(zz, 1) = ii;
           zz = zz + 1;
       end
    end

    % results will only keep rows #1, 11, 21, 31, ... of mydata 
    results = mydata(id, 1);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you import into Matlab, there's no need to delete rows.  You can just replace everything with your selected rows.  For example, if you import into a variable called Data:

```
[r,c] = size (Data);  %So you know the number of rows.  Then you want every 10 rows begining with row 1, keeping all the columns
Data = Data(1:10:r, :);
```